# source command error from /usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion when I open a terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

When I open terminal I get these errors:

```
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 171: `}'
```

And it's because of this area of the `bash-completion` file:

```
_upvar()
{
    if unset -v "$1"; then           # Unset & validate varname
        if (( $# == 2 )); then
            eval $1=\"\$2\"          # Return single value
        else
            eval $1=\(\"\${@:2}\"\)  # Return array
        fi
    fi
}
```

Why do I get an error in that part?

Comment: I tried `source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and got no syntax error. Please post the output of `lsb_release -d` and `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: Can you please add your bash version (`echo $BASH_VERSION`) and also the output of `cat -net src` so we can see if there are any funny characters that may be affecting things

Comment: ... for example, I can reproduce the error if I add a carriage return after the final `fi`

Comment: @Terrance I'm slightly confused as to what you mean there

Comment: Tara I. would file a bug report on launchpad.net if I were getting that error.

Comment: @Terrance Well, you're right, there's only function here, so we've no way of telling if it's issue with positional parameters. But the unsetting/setting itself is wrong. The smart thing to do would be to use `shift` function. That way you don't need to transfer anything.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I have retracted my close vote. I have looked further into this.  This actually appears to be a segment of the `/var/share/bash-completion/bash-completion` file from Ubuntu 18.04.   Without seeing the entire file there is no way to know if there is a typo or something in that area of line 171 that doesn't have a matching `{`.  I am going to agree with WinEunuuchs2Unix above about this being a bug then.

Comment: @TaraSVolpe Did you edit the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` in any way ?  Was the empty newline between function name and bracket there or was it just a typo on your part in the original edit of your question ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `md5sum /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt-cache policy "$(dpkg-query -S /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion | cut -d : -f 1)"`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be the same issue as [this U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290869/70524): you have an alias for `fi`. The script is fine under most circumstances, but aliasing shell keywords can cause unexpected problems:

```
$ alias fi=find
$ . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 171: `}'
```

That function, despite being around line 170, is the first place in that file which uses `fi`. Depending on where exactly you placed this alias definition, and where exactly the bash-completion scripts are being sourced by bash, this might be the first time after that alias is set that `fi` is used.

Answer (score 4):

To see if any of your aliases are conflicting with a bash built-in or a system command use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -i

# NAME: alias-check
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: Verify alias doesn't conflict with bash built-in
# DATE: June 17, 2018.

# Get aliases
alias > /tmp/alias.lst
sed -i 's/=.*//; s/alias //g' /tmp/alias.lst
#cat /tmp/alias.lst
while read -r line 
do 
   command type -a ${line}
done< /tmp/alias.lst
```

##Testing bad aliases

Edit `~/.bashrc` and insert these "bad" aliases:

```
alias fi=find
alias test='ls test'
```

Now run the script `alias-check`:

```
bash: /home/rick/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error: unexpected end of file
alert is aliased to `notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e 's/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//')"'
cdh is aliased to `cd /home/rick'
cdo is aliased to `cd /mnt/old'
cdt is aliased to `cd /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2'

egrep is aliased to `egrep --color=auto'
egrep is /bin/egrep
fgrep is aliased to `fgrep --color=auto'
fgrep is /bin/fgrep
fi is aliased to `find'
fi is a shell keyword
grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto'
grep is /bin/grep
l is aliased to `ls -CF'
la is aliased to `ls -A'
ll is aliased to `ls -alF'
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
lsdrv is aliased to `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL'
redalert is aliased to `notify-send --urgency=critical -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e 's/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//')"'
sudo is aliased to `sudo '
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
test is aliased to `ls test'
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
zenity is aliased to `zenity 2>/dev/null'
zenity is /mnt/e/usr/local/bin/zenity
zenity is /usr/local/bin/zenity
zenity is /usr/bin/zenity
```

Notice the lines:

- fi is a **shell keyword**
- test is a **shell builtin**

Look for these types of errors in your aliases.

After testing don't forget to remove the aliases `fi` and `test` and save `~/.bashrc` again.

You can't run the test by simply issuing alias at the command line because the first line of the script `#!/bin/bash -i` loads a new shell using `~/.bashrc`.