# unsuccessful source .bash_profile from a shell script

Tags: bash, oracle

Normally, I can source ~/.bash_profile file as oracle using this command, but when I created a new file named test for another instance.

```
#!/bin/bash

# User specific environment and startup programs
# Oracle Settings

# User specific environment and startup programs
if ! [[ "$PATH" =~ "$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:" ]]
then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
#export PATH

# Oracle Settings

export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=agile
export ORA_INVENTORY=/opt/app/oraInventory
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch

export DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"
export LC_ALL=C

alias sp='sqlplus / as sysdba'
alias script='cd /u02/scripts/agile'
alias software='cd /u02/software'
alias export='cd /u02/backup/export'
```

When I source this in a shell script and execute it, it throw me an errors of cd: too many arguments.  I tried . (dot) instead of source. Same result.

```
$ source test
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

When I give "test" `$ chmod a+x ~/test` and source it, I get charset error:

```
$ ls -ltr test
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 724 Oct  6 14:37 test
$ souce test
GLib: Cannot convert message: Could not open converter from “UTF-8” to “AL32UTF8”
```

added export CHARSET=AL32UTF8 on test file and source it, I got the same error as beginning:

```
$ vi test
$ source test
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

even I source the main one but it's ok when su - oracle from root.

```
$ source .bash_profile
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

no error when source as root

```
[root@ ~]# source ~oracle/test
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue is almost certainly your unfortunate choice of name for the alias `export='cd /u02/backup/export'` - which overwrites the shell builtin of the same name.

In particular, if your source the script a second time in the same shell, it will result in expressions like

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1
```

becoming

```
cd /u02/backup/export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
cd /u02/backup/export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1
```

in which `cd` is passed "too many arguments".

See the somewhat related [source command error from /usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion when I open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046930/source-command-error-from-usr-share-bash-completion-bash-completion-when-i-open)

Comment: even the "test" file has only export oracle_sid=agile and no alias at all.  

"export ORACLE_SID=agile"

still give me error of -bash: cd: too many arguments

used to source different oracle_sid profile  fine in rhel6 and rhel7

Comment: @Pepe perhaps it is aliased elsewhere? You can check with `type -a export`. You may want to check `type -a cd` as well.

Comment: $ type -a export
export is aliased to `cd /u02/backup/export'
export is a shell builtin


$ type -a cd
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd
cd is /bin/cd
cd is /usr/bin/cd

Comment: @Pepe right - so the first time you source your `test` file, `export` gets aliased to `cd /u02/backup/export'`. Any subsequent `export foo` command (for example, by sourcing `test` again) will therefore fail.

Comment: BTW `test` is **also** the name of a shell builtin and should be avoided as a command name.

Comment: I can name `test` to `newagile` and when I source it still same error.

`$ source \~newagile
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
`
the file doesn't have any aliases, only export ORACLE_SID=agile

Comment: @Pepe when you **source** a file, it gets executed in the current shell environment - so it doesn't matter if the file itself doesn't contain any aliases, the alias clearly exists in the current environment (as shown by the `type export` command).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit to steeldriver's correct answer:
Note that in the first 3 of the alias commands, the proposed alias is printed in black. In the 4th, however, the word export is colored. This is the first clue that export is in some way special, which it is as steeldriver has explained.

Comment: even set the new oracle_sid **bold** `$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [myhr] ? agile
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
ORACLE_HOME = [] ? `
waiting for me to enter oracle_home.  Once the oracle_home entered I still get the cd: too many arguments
**bold**`ORACLE_HOME = [] ? /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
-bash: cd: too many arguments
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
-bash: cd: too many arguments `